# Getting wrong answer on codechef.But my math is right

Tags: java

Link of the question-https://www.codechef.com/problems/MATPH
So , I'm stuck on this question for hours and I don't know where I'm wrong.
I have used Sieve of Eratosthenes for finding prime and I saved all prime numbers in hash map.Online judge is giving me wrong answer on test cases.

```
        static void dri(int n) {
            long large=0;int r=0,x,count=0,p,count1=0;
            x=(int)Math.sqrt(n);

            //To understand why I calculated x let's take an example
            //let n=530 sqrt(530) is 23 so for all the numbers greater than 23 when 
            //we square them they will come out to be greater than n 
            //so now I just have to check the numbers till x because numbers 
            //greater than x will defiantly fail.I think you get 
            //what I'm trying to explain


            while(r<x) {
                r = map.get(++count); // Prime numbers will be fetched from map and stored in r
                int exp = (int) (Math.log(n) / Math.log(r));
                //To explain this line let n=64 and r=3.Now, exp will be equal to 3
                //This result implies that  for r=3 the 3^exp is the //maximum(less than n) value  which I can calculate by having a prime in a power
                if (exp != 1) {   //This is just to resolve an error dont mind this line
                    if (map.containsValue(exp) == false) {
                    //This line implies that when exp is not prime  
                    //So as I need prime number  next lines of code will calculate the nearest prime to exp
                        count1 = exp;
                        while (!map.containsValue(--count1)) ;  

                        exp = count1;
                    }
                    int temp = (int) Math.pow(r, exp);
                    if (large < temp)
                        large = temp;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(large);
        }
```

I

Comment: Please include relevant parts of the question/quiz in your question and a more detailed description of what doesn't work with your code.

Comment: According to the link you should handle `N` up to 10^11, but your method takes an `int` argument, that’s not be enough.

Comment: Ole I know but this code is not working even for the values in int range.

Comment: Please Have patience with me , I'm learning. :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson  I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For each testcase, output in a single line containing the largest
>   beautiful number ≤ *N*. Print −1 if no such number exists.

I believe that 4 is the smallest beautiful number since 2 is the smallest prime number and 2^2 equals 4. *N* is just required to ≥ 0. So `dri(0)`, `dri(1)`, `dri(2)` and `dri(3)` should all print `−1`. I tried. They don’t. I would believe that this is the reason for your failure on CodeChef.

I am leaving it to yourself to find out how the mentioned calls to your method behave and what to do about it.

As an aside, what’s the point in keeping your prime numbers in a map? Wouldn’t a list or a sorted set be more suitable?